# Can you filter within a group with Crossfilter

Tags: javascript, lodash, crossfilter

I'd like to do some fast filtering in the browser and have been recommended crossfilter, but having looked at it I'm not entirely sure it suits my data.  So, my data has just 3 variables:

```
{group: "A", value: 39.8, variable: "ABC"}
{group: "B", value: 26.8, variable: "ABC"}
{group: "C", value: 27.4, variable: "ABC"}
{group: "D", value: 26.9, variable: "ABC"}
{group: "E", value: 22.9, variable: "ABC"}
{group: "A", value: 48.9, variable: "ALL"}
{group: "B", value: 32.2, variable: "ALL"}
{group: "C", value: 16.2, variable: "ALL"}
{group: "D", value: 13.2, variable: "ALL"}
{group: "A", value: 42.3, variable: "ALL1"}
{group: "B", value: 50.1, variable: "ALL1"}
{group: "C", value: 19.3, variable: "ALL1"}
 etc
```

I'd like to be able to filter where the values limits vary for each group:

```
  (group = 'A' & 10 <= value <=20) or (group = 'B' & 15 <= value <=95) or
  (group = 'C' & 10 <= value <=20) or (group = 'D' & 25 <= value <=45) or
  (group = 'E' & 10 <= value <=20)
```

Is this possible without reorganising the data or are there better options?

So, this is what I've tried:

```
{group: "B", value: 26.8, variable: "ABC"},
{group: "C", value: 27.4, variable: "ABC"},
{group: "D", value: 26.9, variable: "ABC"},
{group: "E", value: 22.9, variable: "ABC"},
{group: "A", value: 48.9, variable: "ALL"},
{group: "B", value: 32.2, variable: "ALL"},
{group: "C", value: 16.2, variable: "ALL"},
{group: "D", value: 13.2, variable: "ALL"},
{group: "A", value: 42.3, variable: "ALL1"},
{group: "B", value: 50.1, variable: "ALL1"},
{group: "C", value: 19.3, variable: "ALL1"}]

var testcf = crossfilter(test)

const valueDimT = testcf.dimension(({group, value}) => ({group, value}));
valueDimT.filterFunction(({group, value}) => ((group = 'B' && value <= 30) || (group = 'C' && value <= 18)))
valueDimT.top(100)
```

Which gives the following result:

```
[{group: "C", value: 19.3, variable: "ALL1"}, 
{group: "D", value: 13.2, variable: "ALL"}, 
{group: "C", value: 16.2, variable: "ALL"}, 
{group: "E", value: 22.9, variable: "ABC"}, 
{group: "D", value: 26.9, variable: "ABC"}, 
{group: "C", value: 27.4, variable: "ABC"}, 
{group: "B", value: 26.8, variable: "ABC"}] (7) = $3
```

Which isn't what I would expect.  Primarily I would expect only group values of B & C with values below the respective equalities given that's all that was in the filter:

```
[{group: "B", value: 26.8, variable: "ABC"},
{group: "C", value: 16.2, variable: "ALL"}]
```

Obviously I'm missing something - I'm just not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using `filterFunction`

You can filter using a function

```
const valueDim = cf.dimension(({group, value}) => ([group, value]));
valueDim.filterFunction(([group, value]) => /* as above */)
```

Note we are creating a *composite key* here. In an earlier draft I spelled the key `{group, value}` but that doesn't work because the dimension and group keys [must be naturally ordered](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#natural-ordering-of-dimension-and-group-values). An object won't work, because it coerces to the useless string `[object Object]` but an array will, because it coerces to a comma-delimited string with the values.

Complete code:

```
const valueDimT = testcf.dimension(({group, value}) => ([group, value]));
valueDimT.filterFunction(([group, value]) =>
  ((group == 'B' && value <= 30) || (group == 'C' && value <= 18)))
console.log(valueDimT.top(100))
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/rL82bguk/254/).

#### Creating a derived key

It is probably more efficient to derive a key from the data:

```
const condDim = cf.dimension(({group, value}) => /* as above */);
condDim.filterExact(true)
```

#### JavaScript notes

Careful with double comparisons:

```
3 <= 2 <= 9
```

evaluates to

```
false <= 9
```

or true in JavaScript, since `false` coerces to `0`.

You will need to do

```
10 <= value && value <= 20
```

Also be careful about `=` vs `==` - the former is assignment and the latter tests equality.

Comment: Is this what you mean? : ```valueDim.filterFunction(({group, value}) => ((group = 'A' && value <= 40) || (group = 'B' && value <= 15)))```  It's not producing the results I would expect.  It works for one group, but not if I put in multiple groups.

Comment: Something like that! Please edit your question with what you have tried, the expected result, and the actual result. “It doesn’t work” is never a useful bug report. :) Note that [a group does not observe its own dimension’s filters](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#a-group-does-not-observe-its-dimensions-filters).

Comment: Whoops - should have tested my code. Thanks for the repro, I have corrected the object keys to array keys and it works. Also, you need to use `==` instead of `=`. Edits above!

Comment: Thanks, I should have spotted it too - I get mixed up with the syntax between different languages.